# Erro script JS - Canoot read property 'match'

Tags: javascript

Olá!

Este script serve para transformar letras maiúsculas em minusculo, mantendo a primeira letra maiúscula..

Porem na linha `return str.match(/\S+\s*/g);` está ocorrendo um erro:

`Uncaught TypeError: Canoot read property 'match'`

Segue script e segue print do erro:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
    $.fn.capitalize = function() {
        //palavras para serem ignoradas
        var wordsToIgnore = ["DOS", "DAS", "de", "do"],
            minLength = 3;

        function getWords(str) {
            return str.match(/\S+\s*/g);
        }
        this.each(function() {
            var words = getWords(this.value);
            $.each(words, function(i, word) {
                // somente continua se a palavra nao estiver na lista de ignorados
                if (wordsToIgnore.indexOf($.trim(word)) == -1 && $.trim(word).length > minLength) {
                    words[i] = words[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + words[i].slice(1).toLowerCase();
                } else {
                    words[i] = words[i].toLowerCase();
                }
            });
            this.value = words.join("");
        });
    };

    //onblur do campo com classe .title
    $('.title').on('blur', function() {
        $(this).capitalize();
    }).capitalize();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt_nome_fantasia" class="nome_fantasia title form-control input-sm" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Nome Fantasia" >
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloque o html para fazermos os testes

Comment: Em algum monento sua variavel str esta vazia gerando o erro da função match

Comment: str tem seu valor como null, por isso ele esta retornando esse erro...

Comment: @Otto mesmo que estivesse vazia ele não retornaria o erro, nem inicializada ela está.

Comment: @Phelipe, eu incluí o codigo como exemplo, veja que o código faz o seu trabalho, porem com erro.

Answer (score 0):

Simples, sua função `getWords` não está recebendo seu parâmetro, logo ele não inicializa a variável `str` e como não esta inicializada você não pode usar o método `.match`, próprio de uma string.

É por isso que o erro escreve, `[...] Cannot read property 'match' of undefined.`
Traduzido: `[...] Não consegue ler a propriedade 'correspondência' de não definido`

Você deve passar o parâmetro mesmo que vazio, por exemplo se você passasse `""` como parâmetro sua função não retornaria erro, somente não encontraria correspondência no seu texto e retornaria `""`.

---

Recomendo que você insira um breakpoint em:

```
   this.each(function() {
        var words = getWords(this.value);
```

E verifique se this.value possui um valor. 
Infelizmente não podemos te ajudar além disso, pois seu código nem sua pergunta revelam atribuição ou finalidade da variável `this.value`, que esta ligada diretamente ao problema.

Porém uma coisa eu posso te dizer:

> A causa do seu problema é que a variável passada como parâmetro para `getWords`, em outras palavras o `this.value` não está iniciada.

Comment: `this.value` é o campo cujo classe é igual a `title`, ou seja os campos que deverão ter suas strings alteradas, coloquei uma imagem para que veja.

Comment: @wagnerfilho então aí está seu problema, você não pode pegar o valor de diversos itens e colocar ".value" esperando retorno com uma string geral, você deve tratar uma string por vez, talvez funcione colocar sua função no ".each"